# failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/<username>/my-history.git'

Tags: github, git-push

I can't update the source code in the repository on github.com using the following command.

```
$ git push -u origin master
```

The following error is displayed:

```
! \[rejected\]        master -\> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/\<username\>/my-history.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Is there any way to do this?

I want to push the source code in the my repository.

Comment: The error message is rather clear: `You may want to first integrate the remote changes (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.` Did you try this first?

Comment: Yes, I tried. 
But the following message is displayed.
From https://github.com/Dream0804/my-history
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I experienced something similar to this a few days ago.

You can do something like this:

```
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/username/my-repo.git
$ git push -f origin master
```

Comment: `push -f` should not the only solution here. It overwrites the remote history. I would go for `git pull` first when I see the `failed to push some refs` error. Maybe someone else changed thing and the HEAD is not up-to-date anymore, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493055/git-doesnt-seem-to-pull-all-updates-head-and-origin-head-in-different-positio